# With Ubuntu 14.04 I get errors related to QGIS when I type sudo apt-get dist upgrade

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Mods - This is not a cross post and please do not flag it as a cross post. I did not receive any answer on GIS - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120759/with-ubuntu-14-04-i-get-errors-related-to-qgis-when-i-type-sudo-apt-get-dist-upg

My question is This happened recently with QGIS 2.4 and Ubuntu 14.04. When I type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get these messages - Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Setting up qgis-providers (2.6.0+trusty1) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.6.0+trusty1); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-globe:
 qgis-plugin-globe depends on qgis (= 2.6.0+trusty1); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.6.0+trusty1); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

You are missing this shared library. You should run `apt-get -f install` to correct problems. This may result in the qgis packages being uninstalled. I'm not sure where you got those *qgis* packages from, but it seems they are built possibly with a new library which is not available in 14.04 (or in the archive you may have installed them from), which is causing the configuration of the *qgis-providers* package to fail.

Comment: thanks. Can this error cause weird problems such as randomly Ubuntu fails to load files properly, software crashes etc ?

Comment: Not likely, no. The only issue you'd have as a result of this, outside of the complaints from apt itself, would be qgis may have issues running.

Comment: this did not fix the problem. Sorry for the late response. Should I open a new question ? I mean I am still getting the errors even after running apt-get -f install.

Comment: Got a similar error when trying to install the current 2.18. /usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl-nss.so.4. None of the other solutions fixes the problem or any of the repos in the qgis site for sources.list

Comment: @Efren - do you have intel compiler ? If so check this answer  - http://askubuntu.com/questions/802585/x-windows-hanging-during-ubuntu-boot

Comment: @gansub the file was not in the filesystem at all :(