# X windows hanging during Ubuntu boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, xorg

I was able to figure out the cause of this problem I was having [Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801816/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-14-04-suddenly). The X server is refusing a connection. I was able to boot by pressing shift continuously and I was able to boot but it does not open the graphics display of Ubuntu trusty.

I tried `sudo service lightdm restart` and `start`. They both don't seem to work. In effect I have access to a tty terminal where I can issue commands and see my data but the X windows access is broken.

Thanks to Serg I installed `gdm` , but that also failed to display.

Then we tried  `sudo startx $(which unity)`

We got this error

```
/usr/bin/X : error while loading shared libraries : libimf.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I looked up the type of display that I have 
it is

```
VGA Compatible controller
product : 4th generation core processor family integrated graphics controller
vendor : Intel Corporation
```

As given by `sudo lshw -c display`

So it is missing a shared library from Intel. Can somebody recommend how to fix this problem ?

Comment: » /usr/bin/X : error while loading shared libraries : libimf.so ... « : The X server or part of it seems to be compiled / recompiled with the Intel `icc` compiler. In your other posting http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298109/what-is-the-purpose-of-libimf-so?noredirect=1#comment524105_298109 you mention /opt///[intel]/ ... Possible solution : Make a copy of `libimf.so` to `/usr/lib/`

Comment: @KnudLarsen - that is a great suggestion. Please add that as an answer. I will upvote it for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion provide by user @KnudLarsen I was able to boot Ubuntu 14.04 and start X server. The key is to pay attention to what Ubuntu is reporting here -

```
/usr/bin/X : error while loading shared libraries : libimf.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

@KnudLarsen then mentioned in a comment that make a copy of libimf.so to /usr/lib and maybe X can find it at that point.

I googled his response and I found a similar posting here:

[Symbolic link to libimf.so](https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2013/06/22174.php)

Which is exactly what I did. I created a symbolic link of libimf.so  in the following way

```
ln -sf /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so /usr/lib64/libimf.so
```

Then I ran startunity again

```
sudo startx $(which unity)
```

It complained of more Intel .so libraries missing. Sequentially I symlinked all of those and finally I was able to boot into X windows.

At the moment I do not know what caused this outage. One thing I do know is that I manually installed the `libGLew*.so` packages and it seems the installer installed those under `/usr/lib64`.