# Can not install openmpi with Intel oneAPI

Tags: system-installation, intel, make, mpi

I have oneAPI installed and environments set. `mpiifort` works, as does `ifor -V`, which returns the correct compiler version.

I am trying to setup openmpi with the Intel compiler, as it is required by CosmoMC. I am configuring it like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ F77=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort FC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort F90=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort ICC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/icc ICPC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/icpc
```

but after that when I `sudo make` some error occurs. The latest is:

```
    ifort: command line warning #10434: option '-nofor_main' use with underscore is deprecated; use '-nofor-main' instead
ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64/../../bin/intel64/../../lib/icx-lto.so: error loading plugin: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1903: libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/souvik/cosmology/openmpi-4.1.0/ompi/mpi/fortran/use-mpi-ignore-tkr'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3555: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/souvik/cosmology/openmpi-4.1.0/ompi'
make: *** [Makefile:1901: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have tried many options like declaring paths, etc., but nothing solves it. The problem is even with some other configuration I avoid the error, but then `mpif90 -V` does not return the correct Intel compiler version.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu?  If so, what version?

Answer (score 2):

I recently bumped into exactly this error. I was installing openmpi to a directory owned by root via `sudo -E make install`, which would fail with the error message you posted. I was only able to resolve this by installing to a directory I own, with `make install` (no `sudo`). I wish I knew why `sudo -E` wouldn't work in this case. I still installed to the directory I wanted to originally, I just had to give it the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error recently and hope my solution will help.

I made a symbolic link of `libimf.so` to the `/usr/lib` (Ubuntu 19 for my case) following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/803437/348964) to [X windows hanging during Ubuntu boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802585/x-windows-hanging-during-ubuntu-boot).

I did the same for later error related with `.so libraries`. Finally it compiled successfully. A similar posting is included: [Re: [OMPI users] OpenMPI 1.6.4 and Intel Composer_xe_2013.4.183: problem with remote runs, orted: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so](https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2013/06/22174.php)

I am a newbee in OpenMPI and Linux so still have no idea about the reason and the library priority setting in Linux yet...